# PHPExpress module segfault error

Tags: apache-2.2, php, gdb

As a part of my server upgrade, I have installed newer versions of OS, PHP, Apache. Also, I have installed [PHPExpress](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpexpress.htm) on my server:

```
[root@dedicated]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

[root@dedicated]# php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: May  7 2012 20:13:47) 
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with NuSphere PhpExpress v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2010 NuSphere Corp

[root@dedicated]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

[root@dedicated]# cat /etc/php.d/phpexpress.ini 
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/phpexpress-php-5.3.so"
```

When I access my site, I am having the error:

```
'The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.'
```

The Apache error log shows the only error:

```
[root@dedicated]# tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Mon May 14 20:16:35 2012] [notice] child pid 23328 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /tmp
```

I've tried to debug the core dump with gdb:

```
gdb /usr/sbin/httpd  core.23328
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fd7fbe48db5 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
```

Could you please help understand what to do further? Why do I get the segfault error?
The error disappears when I disable the PHPExpress module. Unfortunately, I have to use the module and not a gdb guru to provide you with more info.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.